# Excel VBA - String replacement - reg exp?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing some word replacement in Excel VBA. Replacing the word itself, delimited by any special characters (except a-z,A-Z,0-9), and preserving the case.

Examples of correct replacement (replacing `example` with `replaced`):

`One example string` > `One replaced string`

`One Example string` > `One Replaced string`

`One Example, string` > `One Replaced, string`

`One >example< string` > `One >replaced< string` (special character in front and end)

`One dexamples string` > `One dexamples string` (`example` NOT replaced)

I have got it working by using serveral lines, as shown below. Any ideas how to do this with regexp or similar methods?

```
cel.Replace what:=" " & Rng.Value & " ", replacement:=" " & Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & " ", MatchCase:=True
cel.Replace what:=" " & Rng.Value & ",", replacement:=" " & Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & ",", MatchCase:=True
cel.Replace what:=">" & Rng.Value & "<", replacement:=">" & Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & "<", MatchCase:=True
...
```

EDIT:
I have a list of about 1000 words that shall be runned throug the script, and be replaced individually. Thus i need to maintain the case as a variable input. (If match is `Example`, replacement need to be `Replaced`)

EDIT:
there is serveral special characters to handle. eg: ",./\"?()<>;:&". The list has just been to long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Upper/Lower case variability involves only the first letter of the word, then the following code will do that.

*If the case within the word might be mixed, you will need to cycle through letter by letter, and also decide what to do if the length of the replacement is not the same as the length of the found word*

One potential issue with this code:

- `\b` is a word boundary token.
- A word boundary is defined as a position bounded on one side by a word token, and on the other by a non-word token or the beginning/end of the string.
- A word token is anything in the set of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- So if you have strings in your source that start or end with the `_` (underscore), these will not be found.
- If this might be an issue, we would have to change the regex, and also where to look for the "cased" character, or just temporarily replace underscores with some other non-word character (and then change it back after).

---

```
Option Explicit
'Set reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'   or use late binding
Function CSReplace(S As String, sFind As String, sRepl As String) As String
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
    Dim sTemp As String, I As Long

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\b" & sFind & "\b"
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        sTemp = S
        For I = MC.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Set M = MC(I)
            sRepl = LCase(sRepl)
            If Left(M, 1) = UCase(Left(M, 1)) Then _
                sRepl = UCase(Left(sRepl, 1)) & Mid(sRepl, 2)
            sTemp = WorksheetFunction.Replace(sTemp, M.FirstIndex + 1, Len(sFind), sRepl)
        Next I
        CSReplace = sTemp
    Else
        CSReplace = S
    End If
End With

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, there's no need to use regular expressions:

```
str = Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Value
str = Replace(str, " example", " replaced")
str = Replace(str, " Example", " Replaced")
str = Replace(str, ">example", ">replaced")
str = Replace(str, ">Example", ">Replaced")
Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber).Value = str
```

Comment: Thanx. But this will not solve this examples:
One >example< string > One >replaced< string

Comment: @Rune Why not??

Comment: Because of the special charactar in front ">" is not a space

Comment: @Rune Just add this case like other cases - as I did in updated answer.

Comment: Sure, but there is serveral special characters to handle. eg: ",./\"?()<>;:&". The list has just been to long.

Answer (score 0):

Or use regex pattern

```
\b[E|e]xample\b
```

**Regex:**

[image: Regex]

[*Try it*](https://regex101.com/r/leh2lv/1)

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = Array("One dexamples string", "One example string", "One >example< string", "One Example, string", "One Example string", "One example string")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print ReplaceMatch(arr(i), "\b[E|e]xample\b")
    Next i
End Sub
Public Function ReplaceMatch(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .pattern = pattern

        If .test(inputString) Then
            ReplaceMatch = .Replace(inputString, "replaced")
        Else
            ReplaceMatch = inputString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

This needs some development re the Case test:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = Array("One dexamples string", "One example string", "One >example< string", "One Example, string", "One Example string", "One example string")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
      Debug.Print ReplaceMatch(arr(i), "\b[E|e]xample\b")
    Next i
End Sub
Public Function ReplaceMatch(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .pattern = pattern

        If .test(inputString) Then
            If AscW(Left$(.Execute(inputString)(0), 1)) < 91 Then
                ReplaceMatch = .Replace(inputString, "Replaced")
            Else
                ReplaceMatch = .Replace(inputString, "replaced")
            End If
        Else
            ReplaceMatch = inputString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanx. This looks promising. I have a list of about 1000 words that shall be runned throug the script, and be replaced individually. Thus i need to maintain the case as a variable input. (If match is `Example`, replacement need to be `Replaced`)

Comment: Sorry so example = replaced and Example = Replaced?

Comment: I amended the above. It is based on a single match check but can easily be adapted to loop all matches.